# WordPress: Echo custom image size into background URL for Figure

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a PHP echo statement to pull in an image into my background URL for a figure element. This is what I'm currently using:

```
echo '<figure class="fixedratio" style="background: url(' . wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( )). ');"></figure>';
```

This works, but it pulls the main image, no matter what size it is.

I created a custom image size in functions.php called custom-size. I'd like to use that size. I thought I could just add it inside the parenthesis for get_post_thumbnail_id but all it did was create errors.

So this does not work:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <?php echo '<figure class="fixedratio" style="background: url(' . wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'custom-size')[0] . ');"></figure>'; ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
    <figure class="fixedratio" style="background: url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/photo-na.gif');"></figure>
<?php } ?>
```

Any ideas what would work to display my custom size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. If you check the documentation, you'll notice that the [get_post_thumbnail_id()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id) function accepts only one parameter (at the time of writing at least): the post ID. You're passing it the thumbnail size which is not right.

The [wp_get_attachment_url()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) retrieves the URL of the given attachment ID. As the previous function, this one also accepts only one parameter (the attachment ID) so you can't use it to fetch a specific image size.

If you want to fetch a specific image size, use the [wp_get_attachment_image_src()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) function instead:

```
$image_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'custom-size' );
echo '<figure class="fixedratio" style="background: url(' . $image_data[0] . ');"></figure>';
```

2. When you add new image sizes in your `functions.php` file, these new image sizes aren't automatically generated by WordPress for all posts, only for new posts created from that moment on. You'll need to use the Regenerate Thumbnail plugin (or a similar option) to generate them for you. If you don't do this, WordPress will attempt to find an image of size 'custom-size' for a post and if it can't find it WordPress will return the closest one in size it finds (or the original one) instead.

Comment: Interesting. I tried it out tonight but an error came up instead saying "Notice: Array to string conversion" which related to that altered line of code.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Indeed, I forgot that `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` returns an array. I updated the code to reflect that, should work now.

Comment: Sadly, no. It's still returning the same error. When I go look at the code, I see for figure, style="background: url(Array); which is obviously an incorrect reference.

Comment: What does `var_dump( wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'custom-size') );` output, @AdamBell?

Comment: Actually, I just copy/pasted the code from my answer and tested it on a demo site I use for development: https://prnt.sc/ncxogz and https://prnt.sc/ncxn7i. At the top you'll see the output of `var_dump()` and right below the `<figure>` tag with the background image URL so it is working.

Comment: I don't see a var dump. All I see is this:
<!-- Event featured image, but exclude link --><div class="feature"><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>/home/hellod8stag/public_html/wp-content/themes/dadvation/tribe-events/single-event.php</b> on line<b>33</b><br /><figure class="fixedratio" style="background: url(Array);"</figure>

Comment: In Console, I got this: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () Array:1 Here's an example page with the error: https://staging.hellodadventures.com/event/32nd-annual-seal-beach-classic-car-show/

Comment: You'll need to update your question and include the relevant code from your `single-event.php` file, sounds like the code you have there isn't exactly the same as the one from my answer.

Comment: Looks just the same as my code, and that worked on my demo site. How odd. Please add `var_dump( wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'custom-size') );` right before `echo` and report back the results.

Comment: Interesting. This time I got the photo along with this info:  array(4) { [0]=> string(96) "https://staging.hellodadventures.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Cool-Cruise-Car-Show-640x360.jpg" [1]=> int(640) [2]=> int(360) [3]=> bool(true) }

Comment: Ok, I'm guessing the only major difference between your setup and mine might be PHP. Please have another look at the updated code and update yours accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, I think we're finally good now. So thanks for all the help and the patience.

Comment: Don't worry about it. And please remember to mark the answer as accepted if it helped @AdamBell.